# My localhost doesn't use the right path

Tags: php, angularjs, api, slim

I'm making a AngularJS app and I'm using a Slim API. I use my API to get data from my DB.

I was testing my app and I noticed something. I have my app in my localhost, but in a server to and they use the exact same code. I use this code to call my API:

```
angular.module('appDatabaseCtrl', [])
.controller('databaseCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams', '$http', '$log',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $log){
        $scope.testDatabaseItems = function(){
            $http.get('/api/items').success(function(data) {
                $log.info("succes!");
                $log.log(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status){
                $log.error("error!");
                $log.log(data);
            });
        };
        $scope.testDatabaseItemById = function(){
            $http.get('/api/items/' + $scope.id).success(function(data) {
                $log.info("succes!");
                $log.log(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status){
                $log.error("error!");
                $log.log(data);
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

Here is my "index.php" file in my Slim API:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

//nécessite Slim
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


//Instancie une app de Slim
$app = new \Slim\App;

//Associe type de requête avec fonction et paramêtres
$app->get('/items', 'getItems');
$app->get('/items/{id:\d+}', 'getItemById');

//Démarre l'application
$app->run();

// Accès à la base de données
function DB_Connection() {  
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "kevdug_angularjs";
    $dbpass = "*****************";
    $dbname = "angularjs";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}

function getItems() {
    $sql = "select * FROM aj_items";
    try {
        $db = DB_Connection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($list);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}

function getItemById(Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $id = $args["id"];
    $sql = "select * FROM aj_items WHERE id=".$id;
    try {
        $db = DB_Connection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($list);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}

?>
```

If I use the "testDatabaseItems" function in my app on my server, it perfectly works, but when I try using it in my localhost, I get an 404 error:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/api/items"

I know that the reason why I get a 404 error page is simply that the address should be:

> localhost:8080/angularjs/api/items

What I want is that in my localhost version, it use the good path but that I don't need to have a different code for my localhost version and my server version.

An other strange thing is that If I go to http://kevdug.webfactional.com/api/items, I get my json object like I expect, but in my localhost, I need to got to "(my localhost address)/api/index.php/items". I need to specify the "index.php" file for some reason and I would like to not need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the remote server and local server configuration, just use a simple boolean.

```
// the uri-base is for both remote and local server the same
$uri = 'http://localhost:8080/';
```

expecting uri of the current file on remote server to be different than file-uri on local server.
e.g, on remote server it is /www/site/class.php and on local server it is c:/php/class.php if that doesnt work, use another pc-specific fingerprint, or just put a file on the remote-server and check if e.g., file exists.

example code

```
if(strpos(__FILE__, 'c:/php/') === 0) {

  # is local config
  $uri .= 'angularjs/api/items';
}
else {

  # is remote config
  $uri .= 'api/items';
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to do it in my javascript file, NOT in a php file. Plus, you answer is a bit to technical for me, could you make it more simple to understand?

Comment: hi Kévin, in your javascript-file it should be pretty easy to achieve. Here you can just read the domain-name by window.location or something to check if the location is localhost (is local, choose local url) or not localhost (is remote, choose remote url).

Comment: Thanks, your idea is so simple yet perfect for my situation, can't believe I didn't think about it. I used a if statement  to put the path to the API in a var that I just always use every time I need to call my API. I just add the index.php file in the path since I noticed that if I use 'api/...' insted of "/api/..."   it finds the wright api folder... Why si that?